# Name a knowledge base system with a good export feature

Tags: migration, knowledge-base

We are looking to create a knowledge base system in our regional office.  We have tried to convince the national office to purchase add-ons to our help desk software, but so far it has fallen on deaf ears.

If we begin our own KB, the last thing we want to do is spend time migrating data manually, so are there free KB systems with robust export tools?

The nebulous nature of the question is because we don't know if national will ever choose a system, so we don't have a target import to.  As we gather requirements on our team we feel being able to dump the data and massage it into another system might be a good idea.

Right now we are gathering requirements, so anything goes

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use a wiki?  They're flexible, free and easy to use.  Plus as your knowledge grows stale you can easily update it.  Even better, if you need to later dump the knowledge somewhere else, you can write a crawler to do it for you.

Comment: I was hoping to skip the "write a crawler" part and deal with a built in export / import routine.  But your idea seems plausible.